# php - unable to pass multiple parameters in count()

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to post multiple session arrays to my database using a for loop to put every element of an array in the database. With the following code I get this error:

```
Warning: count() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given
```

code

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['name'], $_SESSION['price']); ++$i){
    $Id = $_SESSION['id'][$i];
    $Name = $_SESSION['name'][$i];
    $Price = $_SESSION['price'][$i];

$query = "INSERT INTO custOrders(ID, ProdName, ProdPrice) VALUES('$Id', '$Name', '$Price')";

if (mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $query)) {
header("location:index.php");
} else {
echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli_conn);
}
}
```

If I use just 1 session array, it puts in all the elements of the array in the database but I cant manage to get the other session arrays in. How do I go about fixing this issue? Thanks

Comment: `count($_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['name'], $_SESSION['price'])` should be `count($_SESSION['id'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (as in manual php.net/count)

```
$a[0] = $_SESSION['id'];
$a[1] = $_SESSION['name'];
$a[2] = $_SESSION['price'];

for ($i = 0; $i<count($a); ++$i){
    $Id = $_SESSION['id'][$i];
    $Name = $_SESSION['name'][$i];
    $Price = $_SESSION['price'][$i];

$query = "INSERT INTO custOrders(ID, ProdName, ProdPrice) VALUES('$Id', '$Name', '$Price')";

if (mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $query)) {
header("location:index.php");
} else {
echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli_conn);
}
}
```

Comment: count($a) will give output 3.

Comment: yup, but warning message will dissapeared ;)

Comment: If i will not write a single piece of code, then also no error will come @vladmir. `:D`

Answer (score 1):

From your code it appears that your are expecting `$_SESSION["name"]`, `$_SESSION["id"]`, and `$_SESSION["price"]` to always contain the same number of elements. If this assumption is guaranteed to be correct by the time you get to the `for` loop you can just use `$i < count($_SESSION["name"])` or any other for that matter. If not, you need to decide what you are going to do if the arrays are of unequal size.

Note that `count()` can only take one array.

Also note that you need to properly escape user-supplied input when constructing an SQL query to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: this is correct, all 3 session arrays contain the same number of elements. If I just use `count($_SESSION["name"])` this only puts the elements of this array into my database. I want to put all the 3 arrays in.

Answer (score 1):

**count** — Count all elements in an `array`, or something in an `object`. Returns the number of elements in `array` or `countable`. **count()** may return 0 for a variable that isn't set, but it may also return 0 for a variable that has been initialized with an `empty array`.

> int count ( mixed $array_or_countable [, int $mode = COUNT_NORMAL ] )

[**NOTE**: Counts all elements in an array, or something in an object.]